# Are there any performance benefits of using Asynchronous functions over Synchronous in Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

Now I came across an article that distinguishes between an Asynchronous function and Synchronous functions. From my understanding of the different examples and explanations, synchronous functions are blocked while asynchronous functions are not. But I will like to know if there any performance benefit in using either?

Comment: are you talking about callbacks or async/await?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Are there any performance benefits of using Asynchronous functions over Synchronous in Node Js?

**Yes**, there are significant performance benefits to using asynchronous, non-blocking API calls in node.js.

Because your Javascript in node.js is single threaded, calling a synchronous, blocking function means that node.js can do nothing else until that blocking function finishes.  If this is a server intended to serve the requests of many users, that means that ALL other user requests have to wait to do anything until this one blocking, synchronous function call is done.  That's horrible for a multi-user server.

If you call the asynchronous, non-blocking API, then node.js is free to work on other requests while that non-blocking API is doing its work.  This drastically increases the responsiveness and scalability of your server.

In fact, you pretty much can't have a usable multi-user server process with lots of blocking, synchronous calls in it.  They will simply ruin the scalability of the server.  It is the non-blocking, asynchronous design that gives node.js its best scalability features as it can scale in a lighter weight way than a threaded system that needs to serve every parallel process in an actual OS thread and needs to use thread synchronization APIs in order to access shared data.

Now, suppose you are just writing a single-user script to run locally on your own computer (say you want to process a bunch of text files to index all the words in them as part of some one-time process).  If you aren't trying to work on multiple files at once or serve the needs of multiple users at once, then it may make absolutely no difference at all to your end-solution whether you use blocking or non-blocking API calls because while you are in a blocking call, there's nothing else for your node.js process to do anyway.  In this one case only, it may actually be simpler to code with blocking API calls.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. While it's true that Node is single-threaded, it's still faster to use asynchronous functions. Node can process other things while a file is being read off disk, for example, or while waiting for an http request to complete.